# How do I install the ext-curl extension with PHP 7?

Tags: php, curl, php-7

I've installed PHP 7 using [this repo](http://php7.zend.com/repo.php), but when I try to run `composer install`, it's giving this error:

> - [package] requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

With PHP 5, you can easily install it by running the `yum` or `apt-get install php5-curl` command, but I can't find how to install the PHP 7 equivalent.

How do I install ext-curl for PHP 7?

Comment: install libcurl first ie. `yum install libcurl or apt-get install libcurl`. After that configure your php 7 with curl `./configure --with-curl` and finally make and install

Comment: @Haridarshan Yea okay, but that's inconvenient

Comment: I've build and install php 7 with curl and other extension. You may also need to install devel libraries.

Answer (score 583, accepted):

Well I was able to install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

on my system. This will install a dependency package, which depends on the default php version.

After that restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: ..and restart the service. **sudo service apache2 restart**

Comment: Only if you are using the apache webserver version.  You don't need to restart apache for the CLI version of course

Comment: similarly gd2, xmlrpc, soap, etc - all small letters suffix worked

Comment: Instead of sudo service apache2 restart, sudo service apache2 reload

Comment: This actually depends on the packages available in the APT sources. First, update the APT packages using `apt-get update`. Then type `apt-get install php` and press tab twice. It will ask for a confirmation to display the whole list like `Display all n possibilities? (y or n):` where N is the available number of possibilities. Press Y and you'll get a long list of available packages, out of which you can find the package name that you want. O course, if you have a long list, this will be a little tedious. But still you can narrow it down based on the version.

Comment: for NGINX users on just do  
sudo apt-get install php-curl

service nginx reload

Answer (score 128):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

Comment: you shouldn't specify the version number if you dont explicitly need it. otherwise you might accidentally install an older version.

Comment: Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged. I'm surprised it took you so long to get a single downvote.

Comment: In my case, I had to specify the version for it to work. I guess this is because I had more than one versions installed in my system.

Comment: If upgrading from PHP 5.5/5.6 specifying the version number seems to be required.

Comment: had to additionally do `sudo apt install curl` anyone know why that is so?

Comment: please do specify version number, I was stuck with the same(for elasticsearch php 6.0), after I corrected with verison number it worked.

Answer (score 31):

If "sudo apt-get install php-curl" command doesnt work and display error 
We should run this code before install curl.

- step1 - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
- step2 - sudo apt-get update
- step3 - sudo apt-get install php-curl
- step4 - sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted this, give it a go, it may work.

Comment: Yep, it works. BTW on step 3 you can actually pick a specific php version.

Comment: sometimes it needs to specify version of your php.  for example: `step3 sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl`  p.s. you save me from a long night !

Answer (score 28):

I tried the above solutions but it didn't work for me, just incase there any other person in the same shoes, this is what I did.
I updated apt-get with the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

this i installed with php curl for the version of php that i was using, mine was

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
```

If this didn't work for you, the repository can be removed with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php
```

Comment: Other answers led me to the exact same conclusion. Let's say it's correct for Now, where other answers were correct for their own time.
I'll verify that this works for Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2. This is preferable to the simple "php-curl" which attempts to load a PHP7.2 version, where (for me) I want to keep using 7.1. Don't forget to restart the webserver. After this, where phpinfo() used to show cURL just under the Module Authors section ( Sterling Hughes  ), now cURL has it's own very detailed section, currently at 7.58.0.

Comment: you are the real hero

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The answer with more votes didn't helpe me.

Answer (score 16):

We can install any PHP7 Extensions which we are needed at the time of install Magento just use related command which you get error at the time of installin Magento

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl php7.0-dom php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-simplexml php7.0-spl php7.0-xsl php7.0-intl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-ctype php7.0-hash php7.0-openssl php7.0-zip php7.0-xmlwriter php7.0-gd php7.0-iconv
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't add any value.

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain any new information. Please see the other answers.

Comment: This is a very good answer, as person looking for curl will likely have next question on his mind about mcrypt. And so on, so it is very useful to have everything there.

Comment: Why are these extensions suddenly missing? How to install them in standalone Windows using PHP.ini?

Answer (score 15):

If You have 404 or errors while `sudo apt-get install php-curl` just try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and again try

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

But notice what version was installed (i use php7.3 and php7.4-curl was installed - so it will not work)

try then

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

At the end You may want to restart services like: apache2 or php-fpm:

```
sudo apache2 restart
sudo service php7.3-fpm restart
```

this worked for me.

Check if curl is on the installed modules list for current php:

```
php -m
```

[image]

Comment: Curl is installed, but not in that list... now what? Edit php.ini? (total newb here)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP7.1 ( try `php -version` to find your PHP version)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
```

then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I prefer this answer since it specifies the version number. The accepted answer is not very accurate.

Answer (score 4):

First Login to your server and check the PHP version which is installed on your server.

And then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Replace the PHP version ( php7.2 ), with your PHP version.

Answer (score 3):

I got an error that the CURL extension was missing whilst installing [WebMail Lite 8](https://afterlogic.com/docs/webmail-lite-8) on [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (so on Windows).

After [reading that `libeay32.dll` was required](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) which was only present in some of the PHP installation folders (such as 7.1.26), I switched the PHP version in use from 7.2.14 to 7.1.26 in the WAMP PHP version menu, and the error went away.

Comment: I had to do this as well to get CURL to work.  (I tried copying libeay32.dll from version 7.0.10 into 7.3.8 folder, but didn't work.)  Not sure why this library file is missing from new php 7.3.8 installation.

Answer (score 2):

install **php70w-common**.

It provides **php-api, php-bz2, php-calendar, php-ctype, php-curl, php-date, php-exif, php-fileinfo, php-filter, php-ftp, php-gettext, php-gmp, php-hash, php-iconv, php-json, php-libxml, php-openssl, php-pcre, php-pecl-Fileinfo, php-pecl-phar, php-pecl-zip, php-reflection, php-session, php-shmop, php-simplexml, php-sockets, php-spl, php-tokenizer, php-zend-abi, php-zip, php-zlib**.

https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

Answer (score 1):

Windows users:

> Note: Note to Win32 Users In order to enable this module on a Windows
>   environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, or, as of OpenSSL 1.1
>   libcrypto-*.dll and libssl-*.dll, must be present in your PATH. Also
>   libssh2.dll must be present in your PATH. You don't need libcurl.dll
>   from the cURL site.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Add your C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.15 to your PATH

Restart all services

Answer (score -1):

Try it if you get `E: Unable to locate package {packageName}`

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```