# PHP7 CURL is not enabled

Tags: php, apache

I installed php7 download from [repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.0.3/) for windows, all works good. I am facing problem to enable curl. 
php_curl.dll file is exist in ext folder, and this extension is uncommented in php.ini, but this module is not showing in phpinfo.

This problem I am facing with php7 only if I run php5.x curl works fine.
looking for solution to resolve this. is this issue in php7 inself. Is there a way to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775897/install-ext-curl-extension-with-php-7)?

Comment: I am trying this on windows, updated question with repo link.

Comment: Try phpinfo() and see if you have the right extensions directory.

Comment: have you: - checked to make sure you're in the right directory via purpleninja's method? - enabled the openssl module? - restarted apache? - tried an earlier xampp release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is issue with 7.0.3
I installed [7.0.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.0.4/) 
And all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is find your php.ini file and uncomment `;extension=php_curl.dll` 
this line by removing ;(semi colon), make sure I've installed curl.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't forget to uncomment line:

```
;extension_dir = "ext"
```

in php.ini on Windows machine.