# Getting XML from URL with CURL stopped working after PHP Update

Tags: php, xml, curl

I Use the following function to receive a xml file from a password protected https url.

```
function get_fcontent( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 ) {

    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );
    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302) {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");

        if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) ) {
            foreach( $headers as $value ) {
                if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                    return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value) ) && $javascript_loop < 5) {
        return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
    } else {
        return array( $content, $response );
    }
}
```

everything worked until our server got a php update to the version: 7.0.22

after that i couldnt receive the xml file anymore. i just get an empty response. 
does someone know why?

edit: i dont know what php version was installed before and we cant downgrade it.

Comment: Have a look at your server's error log - is there any error given that might be connected?

Comment: just warnings that my variable (with the xml data inside) is empty nothing else

Comment: Okay, then start debugging it: which parts of that code do still work, from which point on does it stop?

Answer (score 1):

install php-curl again which is compatible with your version. check this answer [How do I install the ext-curl extension with PHP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775897/how-do-i-install-the-ext-curl-extension-with-php-7) if you are linux.