# Guzzle Post Request doen´t work in production

Tags: laravel, post, guzzle

I am making a Post request through Guzzle, everything works fine in my local environment, but in production it does not work, it does not give error or messages in the log file

On my local server I use Wamp Server, with laravel and php 7.0.29. In production I use a shared hosting with Bluehost and the same version of php

```
$client = new Client(["base_uri" => url()]);
$options = [
    'form_params' => $form
];
$response = $client->post("/salud/parte2", $options);
```

I receive status code 200 but when reviewing the database I hope the form is saved but it does not

Comment: I think guzzle uses the [curl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775897/how-do-i-install-the-ext-curl-extension-with-php-7). Is it installed on your shared host?

Comment: yes, it is installed