# How to add curl on php7.2 and ubuntu 14

Tags: php, curl, server

I am trying to install curl on my ubunutu 14 server with php 7.2 installed. I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

but it gives error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package php7.0-curl
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-curl'

I then tried to resolve this issue by running commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0
```

But that also end up with same "Couldn't find package" error.

Comment: You want curl on PHP 7.2 while you install the php7.0-curl, try change it to `php7.2-curl`

Comment: I did bt it is giving same error.

Comment: Ubuntu 14 is now in security maintenance only support so you are not getting anything new. You also can not use Ondřej Surý' PPA because he only supports 16.04+. At this point in time you are probably best to update to a newer version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu distro `trusty` is too old and those packages [aren't available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages). You will have to build the library from the source by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find solution your problem [How do I install the ext-curl extension with PHP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775897/how-do-i-install-the-ext-curl-extension-with-php-7)

Shortly, try to execute

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Also you can use `sudo apt-cache search curl` which shows you available packages for installation.

Comment: When i run command:

sudo apt-get install php-curl

It gives same error of "Couldn't find any package"


When i run search command to see available packages, it shows "php5-curl" and not "php7-curl" . Link you shared have exactly same commands which i tired and giving unable to locate package error.