# Installation failed while install phpunit selenium using composer

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I tried to install phpunit/phpunit-selenium but it shows me few errors. I given it in below:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit-selenium
Using version ^7.0 for phpunit/phpunit-selenium
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-selenium ^7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-selenium[7.0.0].
- phpunit/phpunit-selenium 7.0.0 requires phpunit/phpunit >=7.0,<8.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3, 7.1.4, 7.1.5, 7.2.0, 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, 7.2.4, 7.2.5, 7.2.6, 7.2.7, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 7.3.4, 7.3.5, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.10, 7.5.11, 7.5.12, 7.5.13, 7.5.14, 7.5.15, 7.5.16, 7.5.2, 7.5.3, 7.5.4, 7.5.5, 7.5.6, 7.5.7, 7.5.8, 7.5.9, 7.5.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Before installing selenium, I tried to install `PHPUnit` and it installed successfully.
I also move the selenium `jar` file to usr/local/bin folder then run it.
I didn't find any solution. Can anyone help me out for this?

Comment: You need to install/enable PHP's curl extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775897/how-do-i-install-the-ext-curl-extension-with-php-7

Comment: Its PHP curl extension check it @catcon

Comment: after install curl still getting issues. @catcon

Comment: Show us your `composer.json` file. "phpunit/phpunit-selenium 7.0.0 requires phpunit/phpunit >=7.0,<8.0 ..." You're phpunit version is not compatible with the version of `phpunit/phpunit-selenium` that you're trying to install.